# Calling a callback function once forEach is complete using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Okay, so this question has been asked before, but I didn't see an answer that I liked and think I found a solution, but would like to confirm.  Basically I'm calling a function in React that has a `forEach` loop within it.  I need to wait to do something after the `forEach` loop has completed.

Can I use `setTimeout(function(){},0)` for this?  I know that `setTimeout` gets called once the stack is cleared, but does that apply to async functions?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
function doSomethingAsync(){
  arr.forEach(function(){
    //loop through this thing
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
   callback()
  }, 0);
};
```

I've been testing this for the last 30 minutes and it is doing what I want...but I don't want to assume that this is going to be a consistent approach.  Thoughts?

Comment: what you do _inside_ forEach?

Comment: `forEach` is not asynchronous

Comment: @ekuusela, but functions inside, can be async

Comment: *"so this question has been asked before"* Then link that answer, and say **what** about the answers you didn't like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically I'm calling a function in React that has a forEach loop within it. I need to wait to do something after the forEach loop has completed.
>
> Can I use setTimeout(function(){},0) for this?

No. There are two possibilities:

1. The `forEach` is doing synchronous work, in which case `setTimeout` is unnecessary and pointless — the function containing it won't return until the loop is complete, and so you can just do your next thing after your call to that function.
2. The `forEach` is starting *asynchronous* work, in which case `setTimeout` is just introducing a chaotic condition: It may fire before the async work is complete, or it may fire after the async work is complete. If you need a callback when all of those async requests have completed, the function you're calling will have to provide that for you to use.

So either you don't need it, or you can't use it.

Comment: Hi TJ, thanks.  I mispoke in my question. The function that forEach is in is asynchronous.  This leaves me with the second option, correct?

Comment: @ElliottMcNary: If either the function you're calling that *calls* `forEach` is asynchronous or the code in the `forEach` callback is asynchronous, you'll need some kind of completion callback from what you're calling. `setTimeout` will be chaotic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!